# PHP: process all regex matches

Tags: php, regex

On the site that I am working on, users can create their own pages where they can upload their work such as music, art, picture etc.

Each page have a "about this page" section where users can put what ever info they need.  We want to expand that and allow them to use custom markup such as links, images etc...

Right now, I'm stuck at adding the link markup, the format that I was thinking of using for the markup is:

```
    [link]http://url.com,descriptyion[/link]
```

and it needs to be converted to this:

```
    <a href='http://url.com'>desciption</a>
```

The problem is, the description that will contain the markup is in a paragraph format and will have multiple links:

```
    This is a page description that will contain multiple link markups such
    as [link]http://url.com,this[/link] and [link]http://url.com,this too[/link].
```

I know how to regex, and capture the results but I've never had to work on more complex such as this... My brain kind of just stopped working after 3 hrs of thinking about this as I do not even know where to start.

To summarize my question:
I need to find all regex match from a paragraph, process the match then        inject it back to the paragraph at the same location.

Comment: you need to use preg_replace

Comment: https://github.com/erusev/parsedown No need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: That looks a lot like BBCode. [PHP can already do that](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.bbcode.php).

Comment: @Robert, Thanks for the reply, I was going to do that but I not really sure what I should put as the $replacement as I need to process the matches first before I can insert them.  Also, $replacement is also not going to be static so I may have to forech() matches and $replacements?

Comment: @vascowhite, thanks, BBCodes seems like a very useful tool, I just do not know how to get started with that either... Is that a library that I need to install?

Comment: @Steve, Thanks, I'll look into that.

Comment: It's all explained in the link in my previous comment. Also look here http://www.bbcode.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with some [regex](https://regex101.com/r/dE5bW5/1) groups

```
$str = ' This is a page description that will contain multiple link markups such
as [link]http://url.com,this[/link] and [link]http://url.com,this too[/link].';

echo preg_replace('#\[link\](.*?),(.*?)\[\/link\]#', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $str);
```

Also it is important to escape some characters used by regex like `[ ] \` etc.

[Working fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/953b314d6bdebeac094f894eff6bfeed95041539)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Markdown as per Steve's comment.

If you really want a custom link syntax, a regular expression like this would suffice:

```
$outputString = preg_replace('/\[link\]([^,\[\]]+),([^,\[\]]+)\[\/link\]/i', '<a href="\\1">\\2</a>', $inputString);
```

Example test:

```
$inputString = 'This is a page description that will contain multiple link markups such
    as [link]http://url.com,this[/link] and [link]http://url.com,this too[/link].';

$expectedOutputString = 'This is a page description that will contain multiple link markups such
    as <a href="http://url.com">this</a> and <a href="http://url.com">this too</a>.';

$actualOutputString = preg_replace('/\[link\]([^,\[\]]+),([^,\[\]]+)\[\/link\]/i', '<a href="\\1">\\2</a>', $inputString);

if ($expectedOutputString === $actualOutputString) {
    echo 'CORRECT';
} else {
    echo 'INCORRECT';
    echo $expectedOutputString . ' !== ' . $actualOutputString;
}

// OUTPUT: CORRECT
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I'm open to using anything that will make my life easier :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex:

```
/(?:\[link\])(.*?),(.*?)(?:\[\/link\])/gi
```

and replace with

```
<a href='$1'>$2</a>
```

[Demo and Explaination](https://regex101.com/r/cO7oR1/2)

Comment: Hi there, unfortunately, my work computer doesnt allow me to open that link... I will check it out when I get home